# How can I change my uid without opening another user account?

Tags: ubuntu, user-accounts

I'm using ubuntu 10.10. I wish to change my user id.

How can I change it without opening another account?

I tried using `System->Administration->Users and Groups` but I got a message saying the user is logged in (which is true, that's me!).

Also tried using the shell:

```
dave@mypc:~$ sudo usermod -u 875 dave
[sudo] password for dave: 
usermod: user dave is currently logged in
```

So what can I do?

Comment: You might get a better/quicker answer over on http://askubuntu.com

Comment: There is a solution at http://askubuntu.com/questions/16700/how-can-i-change-my-own-user-id

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to log with a different account in order to change the `dave` account.

Either log in as another (temprarily created for this purpose) user and use `sudo` as you tried in your question, or log in as `root` at a text console (CTRL-ALT-F1 etc).

Before you can log in directly as root, you will have to enable it by setting a password (use the command `sudo passwd root`. To re-disable the root login afterwards log in as yourself and use the command `sudo usermod -p '!' root`).

Answer (score 1):

Log out, switch to a text console, log in as root, and then run `usermod` to change the UID, and then run `find` to find all files owned by the old UID and change them.